# Why TaskFactory.StartNew Task is not starting immediately?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, asynchronous

As per the [MSDN Documentation TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) it Creates and starts a Task. So, for the below code sample

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t =Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => SomeLongRunningCalculation(10, Display)
            );
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => SomeLongRunningCalculation(20, Display)
            );
        Console.WriteLine("Invoked tasks");
        Task.WaitAll(t, t1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Display(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public static void SomeLongRunningCalculation(int j, Action<int> callBack)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking calculation for {0}", j);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (callBack != null)
        {
            callBack(j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

My expected output was

> ```
> Invoking calculation for 10
> Invoking calculation for 20
> Invoked tasks
> 11 
> 21
> ```

But, it is displaying

> ```
> Invoked tasks
> Invoking calculation for 20
> Invoking calculation for 10
> 21
> 11
> ```

I would like to learn

1. Why the tasks are not running immediately after StartNew?
2. What should I do, to get the output in the expected format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very likely outcome on a machine with a single core cpu.  Or possible on one with a multi-core cpu and it is also busy doing something else.

Creating a task or a thread only sets up a logical operating system structure that allows code to run.  The operating system scheduler does *not* immediately start executing it if the cores are busy, the thread has to compete with all the other threads that are running on the machine.  A typical Windows session has a thousand or so.  64 times per second, the kernel generates an interrupt and the scheduler re-evaluates what's going on to see if another thread should get a turn.  Any threads that are not blocking (waiting for some other thread to get a job done like read a file or network packet) are eligible to run and the scheduler picks the one with with the highest priority.  Some additional code in the scheduler tinkers with the priority values to ensure that all threads get a chance.

Chance is the key word here.  Thread scheduling is *non-deterministic*.

Note how I never said anything about the Thread or Task or ThreadPool class.  They don't have the power to do much of anything about the way the operating system schedules threads.  All that's possible is *prevent* a thread from running, the job of the thread pool scheduler.

Priority matters, you can tinker with the Thread.Priority or Task.Priority property to affect outcome.  But no slamdunk, the operating system scheduler constantly adjusts a threads priority from the base priority you set with that property.  You cannot prevent a thread from *ever* running by having another one with a higher priority for example.

Hoping that threads run in a predictable order causes the worst kind of bug, a threading race bug.  Second worst is deadlock.  They are extremely hard to debug because they depend on timing and available machine resources and load.  You can only ensure that you get a particular order by writing code that explicitly takes care of it.  Which you do by using a threading primitive like Mutex or the *lock* keyword.  Notable too is that when you try to add such code to your snippet then you'll end up with a program that no longer has concurrency.  Or in other words, you'll end up not having any use for a Task anymore.  A thread or task will only be useful if you *can* afford for it to run at unpredictable times.

Answer (score 7):

> Why the tasks are not running immediately after StartNew?

Regarding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) `StartNew()` will *schedule* a task for execution.

> Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a Task using
>   one of its constructors and then calling Start to schedule it for
>   execution. However, unless creation and scheduling must be separated,
>   StartNew is the recommended approach for both simplicity and
>   performance.

Since TPL uses ThreadPool threads - sometimes it have to do some work in order to reserve and start a ThreadPool thread for a particular task execution. If you need explicitly run a separate thread without any intermediate mechanism like TPL's TaskScheduler - create and start a thread manually and obviuosly you will not have such neat stuff like continuation.

Answer (score 0):

> Note how I never said anything about the Thread or Task or ThreadPool
>   class. They don't have the power to do much of anything about the way
>   the operating system schedules threads. All that's possible is prevent
>   a thread from running, the job of the thread pool scheduler.

War of ... Tasks vs Threads... It is so depending on the required task.

For the sample, we need load 100 pictures from the Internet with 100 simultaneous tasks (one task for one client) to make map tiles for 100 clients (one tile for one client).  And we have a common time limit, and a load time of some loading tasks can overlaps common time limit.
The simple test shows that, simultaneous execution of 100 Threads (class Thread) for the limited time, much more productive, than execution of 100 Tasks (class Task).
The same result for 10 Threads vs 10 Tasks.
I mean that if we need more than "a few sluggish", but robust, tasks, i.e. to do much more work in simultaneous tasks, then we should use class Thread.